# how to activate existing virtual enviroment (using pipenv)

Tags: django, virtualenv, pipenv, virtualenv-commands

I am working with a project in django where i am using virtual enviroment using pipenv shell (which created enviroment name (Django_and_Rest-YRrszWnq)) so in this enviroment  I have installed many packages releated to this project

Now I started new project and also i want to used above virtual enviroment How to activate this ((Django_and_Rest-YRrszWnq)) enviroment to new project using pipenv command ?

Answer (score 1):

From the environment `(Django_and_Rest-YRrszWnq)` run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then copy the requirements.txt file to the new project. Then from inside the new project folder, run `pipenv shell` this creates a new environment. Then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Now you have a new virtual environment with the exact dependencies as the old environment.

If you find this solution helpful, kindly upvote the solution. Thank you.

Comment: when i used that command it shows my packages name but no such file created

Comment: Did you use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` or just `pip freeze` ?

Comment: Glad to help @AzharUddinSheikh. Kindly upvote the solution if it is helpful.

Comment: No such option available to upvoting your comment 
I can see A flag and your name

Comment: The up arrow near my solution is for upvoting. Near the number of upvotes for this solution currently (i.e) 0

Comment: Don't you think this will be a redundant task where the user will spend time again to rebuild the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
. ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Django_and_Rest-YRrszWnq/bin/activate
```

[image]